How to do "flutter run" on a physical Android device without default log messages?
How can I run flutter run on a physical android device without receiving a bombardment of debugging log messages by Android itself? I have to fish out my own logging messages or print statements when I'm trying to debug my code on an Android device but when running my app on a physical iOS device, none of these default debugging logs show up.
Please note that I'm using VS code and running flutter run via the terminal on it. I need to be able to run it from the terminal. If anyone has a great solution to these messages, it would be extremely helpful.
Here's an example of the messages I would like to hide by default when I do flutter run:
D/FirebaseAuth(27676): Notifying id token listeners about user ( VI1HgxPrdQhAFuXZ95ULH4mMSXp2 ).
I/ExoPlayerImpl(27676): Init 2251360 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [oriole, Pixel 6, Google, 34]
W/test.test(27676): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/Surface (27676): Surface::setFrameRate is deprecated, setFrameRate hint is dropped as destination is not SurfaceFlinger
I/DMCodecAdapterFactory(27676): Creating an asynchronous MediaCodec adapter for track type video
D/CCodec  (27676): allocate(c2.exynos.h264.decoder)
I/Codec2Client(27676): Available Codec2 services: "default" "default1" "default2" "software"
I/CCodec  (27676): setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
I/CCodec  (27676): Created component [c2.exynos.h264.decoder]
D/CCodecConfig(27676): read media type: video/avc
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): ignored struct field coded.color-format.locations
D/CCodecConfig(27676): ignoring local param raw.size (0xd2001800) as it is already supported
D/CCodecConfig(27676): ignoring local param default.color (0x5200180b) as it is already supported
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): ignored struct field raw.hdr-static-info.mastering
I/CCodecConfig(27676): query failed after returning 15 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig(27676): c2 config diff is Dict {
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 algo.low-latency.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::i32 algo.priority.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::float algo.rate.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 20496
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 20481
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.matrix = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.primaries = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.range = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.transfer = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 default.color.matrix = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 default.color.primaries = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 default.color.range = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 default.color.transfer = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 input.buffers.max-size.value = 7340032
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   string input.media-type.value = "video/avc"
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   string output.media-type.value = "video/raw"
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.color.range = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::float raw.hdr-static-info.max-cll = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::float raw.hdr-static-info.max-fall = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.max-size.height = 240
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.max-size.width = 320
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.pixel-format.value = 34
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::i32 raw.rotation.flip = 
W/ColorUtils(27676): expected specified color aspects (0:0:0:0)
I/MediaCodec(27676): MediaCodec will operate in async mode
D/SurfaceUtils(27676): connecting to surface 0xb400006fa379f940, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(27676): [c2.exynos.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 28340225
D/SurfaceUtils(27676): disconnecting from surface 0xb400006fa379f940, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(27676): connecting to surface 0xb400006fa379f930, reason connectToSurface(reconnect-with-listener)
D/CCodec  (27676): [c2.exynos.h264.decoder] buffers are bound to CCodec for this session
D/CCodecConfig(27676): no c2 equivalents for log-session-id
D/CCodecConfig(27676): no c2 equivalents for color-standard
D/CCodecConfig(27676): no c2 equivalents for csd-1
D/CCodecConfig(27676): no c2 equivalents for native-window
D/CCodecConfig(27676): no c2 equivalents for native-window-generation
D/CCodecConfig(27676): no c2 equivalents for flags
D/CCodecConfig(27676): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 default.color.matrix = 1
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 default.color.primaries = 1
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 default.color.range = 2
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 default.color.transfer = 3
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.max-size.height = 1280
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.max-size.width = 720
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.size.height = 1280
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.size.width = 720
W/Codec2Client(27676): query -- param skipped: index = 1107298332.
D/CCodec  (27676): client requested max input size 212611, which is smaller than what component recommended (7340032); overriding with component recommendation.
W/CCodec  (27676): This behavior is subject to change. It is recommended that app developers double check whether the requested max input size is in reasonable range.
D/CCodec  (27676): encoding statistics level = 0
D/CCodec  (27676): setup formats input: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t height = 1280
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t level = 65536
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t max-input-size = 7340032
D/CCodec  (27676):   string mime = "video/avc"
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t priority = 0
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t profile = 65536
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t width = 720
D/CCodec  (27676):   Rect crop(0, 0, 719, 1279)
D/CCodec  (27676): }
D/CCodec  (27676): setup formats output: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t android._color-format = 2130708361
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t android._video-scaling = 1
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t rotation-degrees = 0
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t color-standard = 1
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t color-range = 2
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t color-transfer = 3
D/CCodec  (27676):   float cta861.max-cll = 0.000000
D/CCodec  (27676):   float cta861.max-fall = 0.000000
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t sar-height = 1
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t sar-width = 1
D/CCodec  (27676):   Rect crop(0, 0, 719, 1279)
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t width = 720
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t height = 1280
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t max-height = 1280
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t max-width = 720
D/CCodec  (27676):   string mime = "video/raw"
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t priority = 0
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t android._dataspace = 260
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t color-format = 2130708361
D/CCodec  (27676): }
I/CCodecConfig(27676): query failed after returning 15 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig(27676): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 1
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 1
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.color.range = 2
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 3
D/MediaCodec(27676): keep callback message for reclaim
W/Codec2Client(27676): query -- param skipped: index = 1073743886.
W/Codec2Client(27676): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
D/C2Store (27676): debug.c2.use_dmabufheaps set, forcing DMABUF Heaps
D/C2Store (27676): Using DMABUF Heaps
D/CCodecBufferChannel(27676): [c2.exynos.h264.decoder#354] Created input block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 17 - OK (0)
I/CCodecBufferChannel(27676): [c2.exynos.h264.decoder#354] Created output block pool with allocatorID 18 => poolID 1056 - OK
D/CCodecBufferChannel(27676): [c2.exynos.h264.decoder#354] Configured output block pool ids 1056 => OK
D/Codec2-OutputBufferQueue(27676): remote graphic buffer migration 0/0
D/Codec2Client(27676): setOutputSurface -- failed to set consumer usage (6/BAD_INDEX)
D/Codec2Client(27676): setOutputSurface -- generation=28340225 consumer usage=0x900
D/Codec2Client(27676): Surface configure completed
I/DMABUFHEAPS(27676): Using DMA-BUF heap named: system
I/DMCodecAdapterFactory(27676): Creating an asynchronous MediaCodec adapter for track type audio
D/CCodec  (27676): allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
I/CCodec  (27676): setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
I/CCodec  (27676): Created component [c2.android.aac.decoder]
D/CCodecConfig(27676): read media type: audio/mp4a-latm
D/CCodecConfig(27676): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 6
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
D/Codec2-OutputBufferQueue(27676): set max dequeue count 13 from update
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(27676): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/CCodecBufferChannel(27676): [c2.exynos.h264.decoder#354] Ignoring stale input buffer done callback: last flush index = 0, frameIndex = 0
D/Codec2-OutputBufferQueue(27676): set max dequeue count 13 from update
D/Codec2-OutputBufferQueue(27676): set max dequeue count 13 from update
I/CCodecConfig(27676): query failed after returning 20 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig(27676): c2 config diff is Dict {
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.aac-packaging.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.bitrate.value = 64000
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 8192
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::i32 coding.drc.album-mode.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::float coding.drc.attenuation-factor.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::float coding.drc.boost-factor.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::i32 coding.drc.effect-type.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::float coding.drc.encoded-level.value = 0.25
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::float coding.drc.reference-level.value = -16
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 input.buffers.max-size.value = 8192
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 input.delay.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   string input.media-type.value = "audio/mp4a-latm"
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 2
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::float output.drc.output-loudness.value = 0.25
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   string output.media-type.value = "audio/raw"
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.channel-mask.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.max-channel-count.value = 8
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.sample-rate.value = 44100
D/CCodecConfig(27676): }
I/MediaCodec(27676): MediaCodec will operate in async mode
D/CCodec  (27676): [c2.android.aac.decoder] buffers are bound to CCodec for this session
D/CCodecConfig(27676): no c2 equivalents for log-session-id
D/CCodecConfig(27676): no c2 equivalents for flags
D/CCodecConfig(27676): config failed => CORRUPTED
D/CCodecConfig(27676): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 2
W/Codec2Client(27676): query -- param skipped: index = 1107298332.
D/CCodec  (27676): client requested max input size 51, which is smaller than what component recommended (8192); overriding with component recommendation.
W/CCodec  (27676): This behavior is subject to change. It is recommended that app developers double check whether the requested max input size is in reasonable range.
D/CCodec  (27676): encoding statistics level = 0
D/CCodec  (27676): setup formats input: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t bitrate = 64000
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t channel-count = 2
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t channel-mask = 0
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t level = 0
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t max-input-size = 8192
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t max-output-channel-count = 8
D/CCodec  (27676):   string mime = "audio/mp4a-latm"
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t profile = 2
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100
D/CCodec  (27676): }
D/CCodec  (27676): setup formats output: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-drc-output-loudness = -1
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t channel-count = 2
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t channel-mask = 0
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t max-output-channel-count = 8
D/CCodec  (27676):   string mime = "audio/raw"
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100
D/CCodec  (27676):   int32_t android._config-pcm-encoding = 2
D/CCodec  (27676): }
I/CCodecConfig(27676): query failed after returning 20 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/MediaCodec(27676): keep callback message for reclaim
W/Codec2Client(27676): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
W/Codec2Client(27676): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
W/Codec2Client(27676): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
D/CCodecBufferChannel(27676): [c2.android.aac.decoder#428] Created input block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 18 - OK (0)
I/CCodecBufferChannel(27676): [c2.android.aac.decoder#428] Created output block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 1316 - OK
D/CCodecBufferChannel(27676): [c2.android.aac.decoder#428] Configured output block pool ids 1316 => OK
D/CCodecConfig(27676): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.channel-mask.value = 12
D/CCodecBuffers(27676): [c2.android.aac.decoder#428:Output[N]] popFromStashAndRegister: at 1000000000000us, output format changed to AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t aac-drc-output-loudness = -1
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t channel-count = 2
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t channel-mask = 12
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t max-output-channel-count = 8
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   string mime = "audio/raw"
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100
D/CCodecBuffers(27676):   int32_t android._config-pcm-encoding = 2
D/CCodecBuffers(27676): }
D/CCodecConfig(27676): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.crop.height = 1280
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.crop.left = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.crop.top = 0
D/CCodecConfig(27676):   c2::u32 raw.crop.width = 720
D/FlutterBranchSDK(27676): triggered setupBranch
D/SessionLifecycleClient(27676): Sending lifecycle 2 to service
D/FlutterBranchSDK(27676): triggered onNewIntent
D/SessionLifecycleService(27676): Activity backgrounding at 280678023
D/FlutterBranchSDK(27676): triggered SessionBuilder reInit
D/SessionLifecycleClient(27676): Sending lifecycle 1 to service
D/SessionLifecycleService(27676): Activity foregrounding at 280678035.
D/FlutterBranchSDK(27676): triggered onListen
D/TrafficStats(27676): tagSocket(240) with statsTag=0x66, statsUid=-1
D/FlutterBranchSDK(27676): triggered onInitFinished
D/FlutterBranchSDK(27676): BranchReferralInitListener - params: {"+clicked_branch_link":false,"+is_first_session":false}
W/ziparchive(27676): Unable to open '/data/app/~~fArrmlbfs7VlP4Bi_xEngw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_631211833-MxtJDt-3dlC3tO5AZ9y6aw==/base.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive(27676): Unable to open '/data/app/~~fArrmlbfs7VlP4Bi_xEngw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_631211833-MxtJDt-3dlC3tO5AZ9y6aw==/base.dm': No such file or directory
W/test.test(27676): Entry not found
D/nativeloader(27676): Configuring clns-5 for other apk /data/app/~~fArrmlbfs7VlP4Bi_xEngw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_631211833-MxtJDt-3dlC3tO5AZ9y6aw==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~9kDi2zmBOH2uNvjZvNtNcg==/com.google.android.webview-qvKmpXppuadiQrPw00UVWQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~9kDi2zmBOH2uNvjZvNtNcg==/com.google.android.webview-qvKmpXppuadiQrPw00UVWQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~fArrmlbfs7VlP4Bi_xEngw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_631211833-MxtJDt-3dlC3tO5AZ9y6aw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand
D/nativeloader(27676): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libedgetpu_dba.google.so
D/nativeloader(27676): Configuring clns-6 for other apk /data/app/~~9kDi2zmBOH2uNvjZvNtNcg==/com.google.android.webview-qvKmpXppuadiQrPw00UVWQ==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~9kDi2zmBOH2uNvjZvNtNcg==/com.google.android.webview-qvKmpXppuadiQrPw00UVWQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~9kDi2zmBOH2uNvjZvNtNcg==/com.google.android.webview-qvKmpXppuadiQrPw00UVWQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~fArrmlbfs7VlP4Bi_xEngw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_631211833-MxtJDt-3dlC3tO5AZ9y6aw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand
I/WebViewFactory(27676): Loading com.google.android.webview version 123.0.6312.118 (code 631211833)
D/TrafficStats(27676): tagSocket(281) with statsTag=0x0, statsUid=-1
I/cr_WVCFactoryProvider(27676): Loaded version=123.0.6312.118 minSdkVersion=29 isBundle=true multiprocess=true packageId=2
I/cr_LibraryLoader(27676): Successfully loaded native library
I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder(27676): Flushed 6 samples from 6 histograms, 0 samples were dropped.
I/cr_CombinedPProvider(27676): #registerProvider() provider:WV.f7@17ea457 isPolicyCacheEnabled:false policyProvidersSize:0
I/cr_PolicyProvider(27676): #setManagerAndSource() 0
I/cr_CombinedPProvider(27676): #linkNativeInternal() 1
I/cr_AppResProvider(27676): #getApplicationRestrictionsFromUserManager() Bundle[EMPTY_PARCEL]
I/cr_PolicyProvider(27676): #notifySettingsAvailable() 0
I/cr_CombinedPProvider(27676): #onSettingsAvailable() 0
I/cr_CombinedPProvider(27676): #flushPolicies()
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(27676): Compat change id reported: 214741472; UID 10463; state: ENABLED
W/DynamiteModule(27676): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(27676): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(27676): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/nativeloader(27676): Configuring clns-7 for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader(27676): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libedgetpu_dba.google.so
D/nativeloader(27676): Configuring clns-8 for other apk /system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader(27676): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libedgetpu_dba.google.so
W/test.test(27676): Loading /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@com.android.location.provider.jar@classes.odex non-executable as it requires an image which we failed to load
D/nativeloader(27676): Configuring clns-9 for other apk /system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader(27676): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libedgetpu_dba.google.so
D/nativeloader(27676): Configuring clns-10 for other apk /data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~hYtutiLBzEOD1IYRMrW1ag==/com.google.android.gms-83CmeH1GAR8HhgKAGojucg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
V/NativeCrypto(27676): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 305 native methods...
W/test.test(27676): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(27676): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
D/VRI[MainActivity](27676): Draw frame after cancel
D/TrafficStats(27676): tagSocket(159) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/test.test(27676): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/test.test(27676): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/test.test(27676): Background concurrent mark compact GC freed 434896(30MB) AllocSpace objects, 104(4624KB) LOS objects, 71% free, 39MB/135MB, paused 775us,2.447ms total 169.565ms
W/test.test(27676): ApkAssets: Deleting an ApkAssets object '<empty> and /data/app/~~9kDi2zmBOH2uNvjZvNtNcg==/com.google.android.webview-qvKmpXppuadiQrPw00UVWQ==/base.apk' with 1 weak references
W/test.test(27676): ApkAssets: Deleting an ApkAssets object '<empty> and /data/app/~~9kDi2zmBOH2uNvjZvNtNcg==/com.google.android.webview-qvKmpXppuadiQrPw00UVWQ==/split_config.en.apk' with 1 weak references
W/test.test(27676): ApkAssets: Deleting an ApkAssets object '<empty> and /data/app/~~9kDi2zmBOH2uNvjZvNtNcg==/com.google.android.webview-qvKmpXppuadiQrPw00UVWQ==/split_config.fr.apk' with 1 weak references
W/test.test(27676): ApkAssets: Deleting an ApkAssets object '<empty> and /data/app/~~fArrmlbfs7VlP4Bi_xEngw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_631211833-MxtJDt-3dlC3tO5AZ9y6aw==/base.apk' with 1 weak references
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(27676): Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 10463; state: ENABLED
D/ProfileInstaller(27676): Installing profile for com.nutest.test
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0(27676): bufferpool2 0xb4000070a3755808 : 5(36700160 size) total buffers - 4(29360128 size) used buffers - 15/20 (recycle/alloc) - 7/20 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0(27676): evictor expired: 1, evicted: 1
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0(27676): bufferpool2 0xb4000070a37227b8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 23/28 (recycle/alloc) - 13/28 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0(27676): evictor expired: 1, evicted: 1
I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend(27676): Making request to: https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog
D/TrafficStats(27676): tagSocket(160) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend(27676): Status Code: 200


If you use VS Code it would be best to start the app using a launch configuration so that the output will be redirected to the Console tab which allows filtering.
Otherwise, if you run it from the terminal you can still apply some filtering on the output but it doesn't really matter if you are using the terminal from VS Code, Android Studio or directly from your operating system (eg. Terminal for MacOS or CMD for Windows).
The filtering command will depend on your operating system.
Let's assume that you want to display only lines logged with Dart's print(...). These usually have the prefix flutter:
MacOS/Linux command:
flutter run | grep 'flutter:'

Windows command:
flutter run | findstr 'flutter:'

This method could be a good starting point. The drawback is it will filter out lines that don't contain the string even if they actually come from the Flutter log, for example if a single print() call outputs multiple lines.
Another method that I can think of is to redirect the output to a file which you can open with another app like a log viewer:
flutter run > app.log


You can simply do this:
Add this to your filter params !D/CCodec,!D/CCodecBuffers to the input field

